US movie, 80s, maybe early 90s, maybe set in the 50s or 60s US, local baseball team w/ slightly slow player and a love story
Saw it in the early nineties, late night movie. Swedish television (SVT) I think.
The story is set in the 50s or 60s if a remember the fashion and cars correctly. A local baseball team somewhere in the states, a slightly slow (not retarded) player bullied by his team mates, but he endures. In the end he gets the girl. Not the most good looking from the crowd, but still.
That is about all i remember w/ some clarity. Now we get into the haze. I think the title had something to do with cherries, cherry blossoms, morning or something around there. Now this could be a total wild goose.

This sounds like it has elements of Bang the Drum Slowly. It's a film about two ball players playing one last season together.  One of the players, Bruce is a little slow...

...Bruce Pearson (De Niro), the team's catcher, is a player of limited
  skill and intellect. 

And he is dying, but no one except his friend Henry knows.  The teammates give Bruce a hard time until Henry lets his condition slip. Also from wikipedia...

One day when a player teases Bruce, a frustrated Henry blurts out the
  fact that Bruce is dying. He asks that it remain confidential, but
  quickly teammates and Dutch all learn the news. They begin to treat
  Bruce differently and each other as well, and the team's play and mood
  both improve.

Now, Bruce, doesn't get the girl (his girlfriend is a bit of a gold digger actually), but the team does go to the World Series.

Appreciate the effort. But no together with anyone, except the girl in the end. Now when I come to think about it, the girl was not down with the crowd; a little older, not appreciated by the other girls. Thanks for jogging my memory - keep up the good work.
